# Primefaces : table header is caching old values if we use f:facet inside datatable tag

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am facing problem with the caching fetcher of f:fecet inside datatable . Here i have the situation where the no of column are varying based on the filter check so what happening on 1st time after render the page suppose it showing 7 column with their headings now if i make any filter check and press a button for re rendered the screen there here i am seeing the column heading remain same as before ( 7 ) even values of column has changed and it's 5 . Here the expected result would be to 5 column heading . Please anyone can suggest me how to control the caching of column header thanks .

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking for. In first line, you should include the code to reproduce your issue (but nothing more as needed to reproduce it, make it as compact as possible). Second, could you draw what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for your comment . Now i'll try to make it more simple .